# How to iterate through list of lists and return one list?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe and I want to select certain columns and apply the `unique` function to those columns to get a list of vectors with the unique values of each column contained in different vectors.

In this example I am using the `data(mtcars)` dataset.

First I create two lists which contain the indexes for the columns I want to loop over:

```
seq1 <- list(1:3)
seq2 <- list(9:11)
```

Then I create a list that contains those two lists:

```
cols <- c(seq1, seq2)
```

Finally I have a function which should find the values within each list, and the function will use those values as column indexes when the `unique` function is called.

```
i<-0 #create iterating value
mylist <- list() #create empty list

for (num in seq_along(cols)){
  i<- i+1
  m <- unique(mtcars[num]) #create the element to be added
  mylist[[i]]<- m #add each element to list
  
} #creates a list of vectors
```

My expected result is a list of four dataframes, because each dataframe will represent a column index contained in `seq1` and `seq2`.

My code is successful in processing `seq2` (We get a list of two dataframes that contain the unique values of the column indexes specified in `seq2`). The issue is it seems the list of dataframes created when `seq1` passes through is overwritten by `seq2`. What should I change in my function so that `seq1` does not get overwritten?

Comment: `num` takes values `1` and `2` and thus gets the unique values in column 1 and the unique values in column 2.  Instead try: `lapply(c(1:3,9:11), \(i) unique(mtcars[i]))`. That will return a list of 6 dataframes. because `c(1:3, 9:11)` is six values (not four).

Comment: Especially with `mtcars`, you cannot get *"unique values of each column"* of _any_ collection of columns, and expect those unique-vectors to be the same length. Because of this, you cannot get a `data.frame` for any of `seq1` or `seq2` columns. If you share the literal expected output (manually-created), it might be clearer, in case I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: @langtang could you respond with that as an answer so that I can see exactly where you would put your code in the function? I'm just a little confused about formatting

Comment: @r2evans I'm a little confused as to what you mean. though dave's answer gave me the result I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is "cols" is a list of 2 vectors and `num in seq_along(cols)` is just counting from 1 to 2 and not accessing the lists.

In my solution, I unlist "cols" to make a vector of indexes.  Then I can retrieve the desired vectors and make the list of vectors.
Also note the use of `num in unlist(cols)` to obtain the index value and not just 1, 2, 3,...n.

```
seq1 <- list(1:3)
seq2 <- list(9:11)

cols <- c(seq1, seq2)

i<-0 #create iterating value
mylist <- list() #create empty list

for (num in unlist(cols)){
   i<- i+1
   m <- unique(mtcars[num]) #create the element to be added
   mylist[[i]]<- m #add each element to list
   
} #creates a list of vectors
```

Comment: okay so `seq along` was not opening up the two nested lists, but was just seeing what was inside the parent list?

Comment: You can see exactly what `seq_along` is doing by testing `seq_along(list(1:3, LETTERS, 99))`

Comment: @r2evans thank you for that example. though I still don't understand why then my code was returning a list of three dataframes containing the drat, mpg, and cyl columns. according to the logic behind seq_along and the way I was using it (incorrectly), my code should just return the first two columns of mtcars, so mpg and cyl. Why then am I getting the drat column as well?

Comment: I have no idea why `"drat"` is showing up. Verify: `names(mtcars)[1:3]` returns `c("mpg", "cyl", "disp")` and `names(mtcars)[9:11]` returns `c("am", "gear", "carb")`

Comment: @r2evans disregard my comment I don't know what I did to get the drat column but I cleared my environment and reran my codes and I'm getting the expected results now. thank you for all your helpful responses.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid such *C*-ish `for` loops in R. This will give you the desired list of four data frames:

```
lapply(cols, \(x) lapply(x, \(y) unique(mtcars[, y, drop=FALSE]))) |>
  unlist(recursive=FALSE)
# [[1]]
#                     mpg
# Mazda RX4          21.0
# Datsun 710         22.8
# Hornet 4 Drive     21.4
# Hornet Sportabout  18.7
# Valiant            18.1
# Duster 360         14.3
# Merc 240D          24.4
# Merc 280           19.2
# Merc 280C          17.8
# Merc 450SE         16.4
# Merc 450SL         17.3
# Merc 450SLC        15.2
# Cadillac Fleetwood 10.4
# Chrysler Imperial  14.7
# Fiat 128           32.4
# Honda Civic        30.4
# Toyota Corolla     33.9
# Toyota Corona      21.5
# Dodge Challenger   15.5
# Camaro Z28         13.3
# Fiat X1-9          27.3
# Porsche 914-2      26.0
# Ford Pantera L     15.8
# Ferrari Dino       19.7
# Maserati Bora      15.0
# 
# [[2]]
#                   cyl
# Mazda RX4           6
# Datsun 710          4
# Hornet Sportabout   8
# 
# [[3]]
#                      disp
# Mazda RX4           160.0
# Datsun 710          108.0
# Hornet 4 Drive      258.0
# Hornet Sportabout   360.0
# Valiant             225.0
# Merc 240D           146.7
# Merc 230            140.8
# Merc 280            167.6
# Merc 450SE          275.8
# Cadillac Fleetwood  472.0
# Lincoln Continental 460.0
# Chrysler Imperial   440.0
# Fiat 128             78.7
# Honda Civic          75.7
# Toyota Corolla       71.1
# Toyota Corona       120.1
# Dodge Challenger    318.0
# AMC Javelin         304.0
# Camaro Z28          350.0
# Pontiac Firebird    400.0
# Fiat X1-9            79.0
# Porsche 914-2       120.3
# Lotus Europa         95.1
# Ford Pantera L      351.0
# Ferrari Dino        145.0
# Maserati Bora       301.0
# Volvo 142E          121.0
# 
# [[4]]
#                am
# Mazda RX4       1
# Hornet 4 Drive  0
# 
# [[5]]
#                gear
# Mazda RX4         4
# Hornet 4 Drive    3
# Porsche 914-2     5
# 
# [[6]]
#                   carb
# Mazda RX4            4
# Datsun 710           1
# Hornet Sportabout    2
# Merc 450SE           3
# Ferrari Dino         6
# Maserati Bora        8
```

Comment: Hi, is that the exact formatting you used for your code in R? I get `Error: unexpected input in "lapply(cols, \"` and also `Error in unlist(recursive = FALSE) : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default`

Comment: @BrendaThompson Yes, according to the error messages you use an outdated R and should update it. If that's not possible for some reason use `unlist(lapply(cols, function(x) lapply(x, function(y) unique(mtcars[, y, drop = FALSE]))), recursive = FALSE)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
lapply(c(1:3,9:11), \(i) unique(mtcars[i]))
```

Notice that returning the unique values of each of these columsn as a data.frame gives non-sensical row names.  You are better off returning the unique values as vectors, like this:

```
lapply(c(1:3,9:11), \(i) unique(mtcars[[i]]))
```

And if you prefer this as a named list of vectors, you might do something like this:

```
setNames(lapply(cols, \(i) unique(mtcars[[i]])), names(mtcars)[cols])
```

or even this like:

```
lapply(mtcars, unique)[c(1:3,9:11]
```

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to use your codes in R but it doesn't seem to like the formatting. When I paste it exactly as is I get `Error: unexpected input in lapply(c(1:3,9:11), \ ` and when I remove the backlash I get `Error: unexpected symbol in lapply(c(1:3,9:11), (i) unique `. So I'm not really sure how to format your code in R so that it works.

Comment: perhaps you are using a version of R that is earlier than 4.1?  Try `function(i)` instead of the shortcut `\(i)`